# Declaring a field as `f: elems[g] -> one h` is producing a name-not-found error. What am I missing?

Tags: alloy

In a model I am writing, I would like to say that a reading of a manuscript identifies a sequence of tokens in the manuscript and maps them to types; the mapping should be defined for all tokens in the manuscript and should identify exactly one type for each token.  (Types and tokens here are as described by Peirce's type/token distinction.)

When I write

```
sig Document, Type, Token {}
sig Reading {
  doc: Document,
  tokens: seq Token,
  mapping:  elems[tokens] -> one Type
}
run {} for 3
```

an attempt to execute the `run` command produces the error message

> The name "elems" cannot be found.

If I replace `elems[tokens]` with `seq/Int.tokens` (borrowing from the definition of `elems` in util/sequiv) or (simplifying) `Int.tokens` or `univ.tokens`, I get the results I expect.

If I replace `elems[tokens]` with `ran[tokens]` (and include `open util/relation`), I get a similar complaint about the name `ran`.

Using these names elsewhere in the model (not shown) does not elicit this error, so I infer that the problem is not that the functions in question are unknown but that function invocations are unwelcome in the right hand side of a field declaration.

The grammar says of the right-hand side of a field declaration only that it is an expression, and function invocations are allowed as expressions.  So I suppose there is a constraint expressed elsewhere that explains why my initial formulation does not work.  Can anyone tell me what it is?

I can make do with `univ.tokens` for now, but I would prefer the original formulation as easier for my expected readers to understand -- they can squint and think of it as a function call, whereas with dot join I need to pause to explain it to them, which distracts from the core task of the model.  My thanks for any help.

Comment: I do not have a good answer but defining a macro `let elems[x]=Int.x` does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I toyed a bit with the example and it seems your inference is correct. One can't reference a function in field declarations (even if the grammar states otherwise)

What you proposed (`univ.tokens` or `Int.tokens`) is for me the cleanest workaround.

What Peter proposed in his comment does indeed the trick, but redefining `elems` looks too fishy, especially since the `elems` function is already clearly defined for your readers. It could be a source of confusion.

Another idea if you really really insist on using `elems[token]` would be to define mapping as a relation from `Token` to `Type` and then to constrain the left-handside of the relation to consist only of those `Token` present in the sequence. Here would then be your model:

```
sig Document, Type, Token {}
sig Reading {
  doc: Document,
  tokens: seq Token,
  mapping: Token -> one Type
}{
    mapping.Type =elems[tokens]
}

run {} for 3
```